# The Use of '—' mark

Tags: punctuation, em-dash

So, I am reading newspapers quite a lot, nowadays to develop my English proficiency. Going through the contents, I find some of them to have used '—'. And I wonder what's the rule behind it: maybe to expand the answer or explanations like the use of a comma to insert data in sentences.
Below are some examples:

1. Engineer Fabien Esculier has never forgotten his grandmother's unconventional approach to gardening—in fact, it has inspired his career.
2. Plants need nutrients—nitrogen, phosphorus and potassium—and we ingest these through food, before "excreting them, mostly through urine", said Esculier, who runs the OCAPI research programme in France looking at food systems and human waste management.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Have you looked up "em dash" online, in a punctuation or style guide, etc.? Extensive discussions of its use can be found in various places.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan It can be difficult for English Language Learners to research terms if they don't know the name of the term to search for. Once you know the terms "em dash" and "en dash" and the origin of their names, it's easy to see in hindsight what to search for, but again, that isn't necessarily obvious if you're learning the language. Granted, "em dash" is more well known than terms like "litotes" ...

Comment: @shoover I absolutely agree, but it's still useful to know whether OP made any effort or even knows the right term. Those things aren't clear from his post. (There were also some comments above mine pointing him in the right direction that have been deleted now.)

Answer (score 6):

The mark used as you describe is called an 'em dash'. It is longer than the hyphen you have used in your examples. An em dash can be used instead of a colon to introduce the next part of a sentence, and is stronger than a colon (it is used when you want to emphasise what follows) and less formal. Its use is to indicate an abrupt shift in emphasis or direction from the main sentence. Em dashes should not be overused.

> I haven’t been scared by a movie—yet

You can make an em dash on a Windows PC keyboard that has a number keypad on the right by holding down the Alt key, then while it is pressed, typing 0151 on the keypad, then releasing the Alt key. I believe that on a Mac, the key combination is Option + Shift + the minus sign key (next to 0 at the top of your keyboard), but I have no way of checking this.  In most Linux distributions you can press whatever key is designated as the 'compose' key and then press the minus sign key three times.

Some style guides advise inserting a space before and after the dash, others not.

> Spacing around an em dash varies. Most newspapers insert a space
> before and after the dash, and many popular magazines do the same, but
> most books and journals omit spacing, closing whatever comes before
> and after the em dash right up next to it. This website [*Merriam-Webster*] prefers the
> latter, its style requiring the closely held em dash in running text.

[Em dash, em dash - how to use (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/em-dash-en-dash-how-to-use#:%7E:text=Spacing%20around%20an%20em%20dash,right%20up%20next%20to%20it.)

[Colons, semicolons, hyphens, dashes](https://rwc.byu.edu/files/2019/08/Colons-Semicolons-Hyphens-Dashes.pdf)

Comment: On Windows 10, you can also use the combination of the Win(dows)-button and the full stop, `⊞ Win`+`.`. This will bring up a menu where you can select 'Symbols', from which you can choose the em-dash. This is useful for a wide selection of emojis, symbols, and other characters.

Comment: @Joachim, yes, you have to select the Omega (Ω) icon and on my PC it's the third symbol on the 5th row.

Comment: There are three categories from which you can choose: `☻`, `;-)`, and `Ω`. The last category is 'Symbols'.

Comment: @Joachim - yes, I found it, see edited comment

Comment: I noticed, but figured my comment could clarify it some more (since my popup menu doesn't have the same rows you apparently have).

Comment: I would note that instead of an em dash it is also possible (and, I think, more common – I certainly prefer that style personally) to use the narrower en dash with spaces around it instead. “I haven’t been scared by a movie – yet”.

Comment: Also: the [Vim digraphs](https://vimhelp.org/digraph.txt.html) for em- and en-dash are `-N` and `-M`, respectively. As with many other special characters, that's much easier to memorise than numeric codes or strange Mac key combos, and much faster than anything with a graphical menu. It is possible to get Vim digraphs either system-wide via tools like Autokey / Autohotkey, or via browser extensions, or of course in text editors with a Vim mode. Highly recommended.

Comment: Every style guide I've seen (and I've researched repeatedly over the years) specifies that only emdashes can be used to offset phrase this way, and they are to be used without spaces. An endash is used to form a range, or endpoints of a route, again without spaces.

Comment: Since em dashes are used to separate words, not to join them, to me it only makes sense to use them _with_ spaces.

Comment: @gidds - you may think so. Others do not. "Spacing around an em dash varies. Most newspapers insert a space before and after the dash, and many popular magazines do the same, but most books and journals omit spacing" - Merriam-Webster.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, you should be using a dash rather than a hyphen. That is, the line should be longer, and usually have space before and after.

A dash indicates a break in a sentence. A bigger break than a comma, but smaller than a period. Usually you could replace dashes with commas and the meaning would not change. The exception to this would be if the sentence also has commas, when replacing dashes with commas might create an ambiguity.

For example, your second sentence could be written, "Plants need nutrients, nitrogen, phosphorus, and potassium, and we ingest these through food." The meaning would be the same. But because we have "weakened" the break, it might not be quite as clear that the list of nutrients is a "side issue" to the main point of the sentence. It gets a little confusing because the comma after "nutrients" is serving a different purpose than the commas between the nutrients.

But consider if there was only one nutrient under discussion. "Plants need a nutrient, nitrogen, that we ingest ..." etc. Now the sentence should be perfectly clear. There is a nutrient, and I am adding the clarification that that nutrient is nitrogen.

Comment: "the line should […] usually have space before and after" – Should it? Typically, an *en dash* has a *non-breaking space* before it and a *space* after it, but I usually see *em dashes* without space. Either way, space before and after sounds wrong to me, the one before should always be a non-breaking space. (I have heard some people use a *thin non-breaking space* before an em dash and a *thin space* after, but I haven't seen that.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag When I was a copy editor, AP Style mandates spaces before and after. I feel like it looks way better, because if there are not spaces it makes it look like the words are linked, not clauses.

Comment: No, do not punctuate the OP sentence with commas. It could then easily be interpreted as a list of separate things: nutrients and nitrogen and phosphorus and potassium. Never assume that a reader knows that the following items are specific forms or enumerations of the first item in a list (in this case, that chemical elements are specific forms of the general category "nutrients").

Comment: @JörgWMittag A "non-breaking space" is something found in MS Word and HTML, maybe other specific software products, not in general typography. Discussing how you would make it format as desired in a specific software product is a different issue.

Comment: @user8356 That's the point I was trying to make, that if you used commas it now becomes unclear whether nitrogen et al are the list of nutrients, or if "nutrients" is one of the items in the list. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

In the days of the typewriter, or when using fonts or devices that don't provide an m-dash, you can use two hyphens together to signify the dash.

A dash is a signal of a break in thought or change of direction, more significant than a parentheses. It can be used to approximate speech that abruptly shifts topics.

*"Two wrongs don't make a right--but they can be twice as much fun!" she exclaimed, laughing.*

Spaces around m-dashes are a matter of a publication's style. I have worked at newspapers that did not want spaces, and others that did. In any case, the space (or lack of space) should be the same on both sides of the dash.