# Better way to show data while contrasting two subjects

Tags: phrase-choice

So I'm writing an IELTS essay and trying to show data for the mint green category in the chart. Which of the following sentences is the best?

1. The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts **(18% and 6% respectively)**.
2. The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration **(18%)** was triple that of their immigration counterparts **(6%)**.
3. The proportion of people **(18%)** who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts **(6%)**.

[image]

Comment: suggest: for emigrating, not for *their* emigration. English prefers strong verbs. And "with no specific reason". There is no need for a verb contraction. But this is editing and actually not allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3 would be a strange choice. They're all people! Beyond that, both versions 1 and 2 are viable. It's just a question of whether you would rather interrupt your overall thought, for the benefit of keeping the data points close to their labels, or finish your thought and then give the supporting data. Personally, I would choose this, since the point of the thought is to compare those two data, so it's nice to see them side by side. You could even make it part of the sentence without parentheses:

> The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts—18% versus 6%.

(Note, I've chosen "versus" because I'm making a comparison, and [you don't need "respectively](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/authorandreviewertutorials/writinginenglish/use-of-respectively/10252704).")

Comment: Thanks for responding, Andy. In your suggested sentence, I can see that the symbol "-" is just way longer than it normally is. I've seen that from time to time in English passages and wonder if it's different from a short dash or not.

Comment: @KenAdams Yes, it's an "em dash." See [this pdf](https://www.sjsu.edu/writingcenter/docs/handouts/Hyphens%20Dashes.pdf). The character `-`, a hyphen, wouldn't be the right thing for interrupting phrases like that. You can make the em dash [on most computers](https://zapier.com/blog/em-dash-on-keyboard/); on a typewriter, simply typing two hyphens (`--`) is a substitute.

Comment: I see. In the file, they suggest four usages:
1. Introduce (and emphasize) more detail at the end of a sentence without using a colon or semicolon.
2. Introduce (and emphasize) a detail in the middle of a sentence.
3. Emphasize a list already separated by commas.
4. Mark a sudden change in a sentence’s tone.

Then, they say, "One single em dash can be used to mark a break in a sentence in place of a semicolon or colon. This usage can be viewed as informal and conversational; as such, it should be used sparingly or not at all in academic papers." Does your suggestion fall into this case?

Comment: @KenAdams Note, comments aren't really a place for new questions. There seems to be a pretty good pre-existing question on this topic [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/314899/138287); if you have any questions that aren't covered by that one feel free to start a new one! I'm not sure I agree that it doesn't have a place in academic writing. In my [doctoral dissertation](https://libres.uncg.edu/ir/uncg/f/Bonner_uncg_0154D_11176.pdf) I used it 126 times, and no one complained! But maybe it's true that I'm even more likely to use it in informal writing.

Comment: @KenAdams And I think my use in the suggested sentence is more like #1, "Introduce (and emphasize) more detail at the end of a sentence without using a colon or semicolon." I could probably have also used a colon, or parentheses. There are few times that an em dash is the _only_ punctuation option.

Comment: Thank you so much, Andy!

Answer (score 1):

Sample sentence: The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts (18% and 6% respectively).

**BETTER**:

> The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for
> emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts, 18% and
> 6% respectively.

Generally, when using "respectively" as used above, a comma is used at the end of a sentence and not parenthesis.

> The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason for
> their emigration (18%) was triple that of their immigration
> counterparts (6%).

Same remark as the previous sentence: *their* is not needed.

> The proportion of people (18%) who didn’t provide a specific reason
> for their emigration was triple that of their immigration counterparts
> (6%).   The proportion of people who didn’t provide a specific reason
> for their emigration (18%) was triple that of their immigration
> counterparts (6%).

The percentages can go in either position. But I would use the rewrite below:

**BEST:**

> **The proportion of persons (18%) with no specific reason for emigrating was triple that of their immigration counterparts (6%).**

Because: *for emigrating* sounds better and is shorter than *for their emigration.* And "with no specific reason". There is no need for a verb contraction. Persons is more formal than people.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm a bit confused as you used **for emigrating** in your bolded sentence but then **for emigration** in the below one. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: @KenAdams Whoops, I meant for emigrating.